# jQuery Plugin won't work on Subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, subdomain, chromium, tampermonkey

I have an issue with Chromium not loading a jQuery plugin for some strange reason.

If I hit the page through a subdomain, it will not load.  If I hit the page through the root domain, everything works fine.  Also, if I use Firefox, both ways work.

Here's a simple version of what I am trying:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Digital Eagle.net Examples</title>
  <script src='js/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
  <script src='js/jquery.jLog.js'></script>

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $.log('Testing');
        alert('Test worked successfully');

         $('button').click(function() {
            $.log('Testing Button');
            alert('Button Test worked successfully');
         });
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Test Log Plugin</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When I hit this page through, http://digitaleagle.net/example/subdomain.php, everything works fine.  I see the alert dialogs.

When I use the subdomain to access the page, it suddenly quits working!  The link, http://example.digitaleagle.net/subdomain.php, returns a javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'log' (anonymous function)
```

In this example, I am having trouble with the log plugin.  In my actual application, I am also having trouble with a Google Analytics plugin.

Is this a Chromium bug?

Here's my Chromium version info:

```
14.0.835.186 (Developer Build 0) Built from source for Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)
```

I'll keep researching, but does anyone have any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

Update: I have tried installing both the stable and the Dev build of Chrome, and I have the same issue.  When I first open Chrome, I see the alert() dialog, but after that, it produces the javascript error.  I wonder know if it is a Fedora 15-related problem?

Here's my current version info:

```
Google Chrome   16.0.904.0 (Official Build 104662) dev
OS  Linux
WebKit  535.7 (@96998)
JavaScript  V8 3.6.4.1
Flash   (Disabled)
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.904.0 Safari/535.7
Command Line     /usr/bin/google-chrome --block-reading-third-party-cookies --flag-switches-begin --enable-print-preview --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
Profile Path    /home/skp/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

**Update** --

It was my TamperMonkey extension!  I renamed my profile directory ( $HOME/.config/chromium/ ), and it worked.  Then, just to experiment, I disabled my extensions one by one.  As soon as I disabled TamperMonkey, it worked fine!

So, now the question is, how do I get both?  I use TamperMonkey for other things.  Maybe I can open a bug on that project.

Comment: Works for me.  That is an ancient developer build, you should really switch to the latest stable or dev channel release.

Comment: havr you tried referencing jquery with the full path instead of the relative path?

Comment: Your example link (http://example.digitaleagle.net/subdomain.php) works for me in Chrome 14.

Comment: Are you cached with a bad file?

Comment: @mikerobi:  I think I followed something like these instructions to install Chromium: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-chromium-on-fedora-using-yum/  I haven't found anything better yet -- I may have to build it from scratch.

Comment: @Johnny Craig:  I haven't tried the full path, but I did Inspect the page, and I can see the full script in the Scripts list.  Furthermore, I don't see any more javascript errors before the missing log() method error.  I may try the full path just to see, but using the full path, I won't be able to access it both ways.

Comment: @epascarello:  I have tried clearing cache.  If it were cache, it seems weird that I would have the problem on both my original application and this example.  I might try creating a new profile in Chromium and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this over on TamperMonkey's website, and Jan fixed the bug for me.  You can view the thread here:

[tampermonkey.net: subdomain + jQuery issue](http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=116)

To fix the issue, download the [Beta version from the Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gcalenpjmijncebpfijmoaglllgpjagf).  (version 2.2.2521)